# Latex symbols in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latex

I have a dataframe that I'm gonna use some special latex symbol for its columns and indeces. Something like this :

```
pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]})
```

With a small difference that instead of `a` and `b` as the columns I want to have `$\diamond$` and `$\dagger$` symbols respectively. 
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you just want to display the dataframe? You can just use this symbols in your definition `pd.DataFrame({"$\diamond$":[1,2,3],"$\dagger$":[4,5,6]})`

Comment: Thank you @onno but, the if I use $\diamond$ or $\dagger$ the real characters will not appear

Comment: How do you visualize the df? In my Jupyter Notebooks the characters do appear

Comment: O, really? In mine they don't. Do you import any special module/library?

Comment: Did you mean for console output or just Jupyter?

Comment: @b-fg I used Jupyter lab